# gzip an image file through cloud function on storage trigger

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, gzip

I am trying to automate gzipping on image uploaded to cloud storage bucket.
Everytime i upload an image, i want cloud function to run python code to convert it into gzip and move it to another bucket present in storage.

My code is not running. It's giving me File not found error. Also what's the right way to give full location.

My code is  ..

```
from google.cloud import storage
import gzip
import shutil
client = storage.Client()


def hello_gcs(event, context):
    """Triggered by a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for 
the event.
    """
    with open("/"+event['name'],'rb') as f_input :
        with gzip.open("'/tmp/'+event['name']+'.gz'","wb") as f_output:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_input,f_output)
    

    source_bucket= client.bucket(event['bucket'])
    source_blob = source_bucket.blob("/tmp/" + event['name'])
    destination_bucket = client.bucket('baalti2')

    blob_copy = source_bucket.copy_blob(
        source_blob, destination_bucket, event['name']
    )

    print(
        "Blob {} in bucket {} moved to blob {} in bucket {}.".format(
            source_blob.name,
            source_bucket.name,
            blob_copy.name,
            destination_bucket.name,
       )
    )
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We will try to help you with code that you write. Please read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the suggestion. I am happy to get my code corrected instead as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Linux file system APIs (open, shutil.copy) to access Cloud Storge which will not work. Copy the file from the bucket to local storage. Gzip the file. Copy the gzip file to the destination bucket. Use the Cloud Storage APIs to interact with Cloud Storage.

Comment: I see your point. Using of methods like shutil , open might be wrong. Plus, I want to automate this gzipping through cloud function. I can do that manually by CLI as you suggested but i want everytime, i upload an image to bucket, it will run the code of cloud function which will gzip the file and shift it to another bucket

Comment: @tarun - I did not say anything about manually with the CLI. I said to use the Cloud Storage APIs - the ones you are using in the bottom half of your code except that you are copying data to/from Cloud Storage from/to local storage (/tmp).